# How to properly terminate a process that is running in the background via subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess, terminate

I have method that runs a bash script in the background via `subprocess.Popen()`:

```
def my_method():
        try:
            process = subprocess.Popen(["bash", "my_script.sh", "&" ],
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                            )
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error running the script: {e}")
        return process

def caller():
        process = my_method()
```

Now, I want the `caller` method to properly terminate the background script. I tried several solutions like `process.kill()` and `process.terminate()`. But, none of them works. I was wondering is the best solution for this?

Comment: The problem is your `"&"` .  The process you start (which is returned in `process`) ends immediately.  Your script is running in a completely separate process that you can't access.  So, remove the `"&"`.  `Popen` already runs it in the background.

Comment: but I need that process to run in the background. So, the thing is that I am trying to write a small code that launches a local server in the background, makes sure the server is up and running. Sends some requests to the server. And once done has to release all the resources of the server and terminate it. Now, the problem is that I can launch the server in the background, but I can't terminate it properly so that it releases all the resources.

Comment: Maybe you didn't read where I wrote that `Popen` already runs it in the background.  That's why your code can continue to run while the process runs.

Comment: oh sorry. I missed that. Thanks.